# Deduce return type of a function dynamically

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a few functions defined which have return types of void, int, float, float*, etc(some classes aswell).

My cmd is a vector of strings inputed from user. where 0th location is the function name(read_lib, square, open_file) and the 1st location is the argument(/path/to/file , number_to_square) etc.

```
auto find_and_execute(vector<string> cmd){
//for(auto x: cmd){cout << x << endl;}
if(cmd.at(0) == "square") {return square(stoi(cmd.at(1)));} // unsigned_int
if(cmd.at(0) == "cube") {return cube(stoi(cmd.at(1)));}     // unsigned_int
if(cmd.at(0) == "open_file") {open_file(cmd.at(1));}        //void
if(cmd.at(0) == "read_lib") {read_lib(cmd.at(1));}          //void
if(cmd.at(0) == "read_verilog") {read_verilog(cmd.at(1));}  //void
if(cmd.at(0) == "set_top") {set_top(cmd.at(1));}            //void
if(cmd.at(0) == "get_pin") {return get_pin(cmd.at(1));}     // Pin Class object takes in cell argument
}
```

Error: inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'unsigned int' and then 'Pin'

Edit: I have another question. All my functions do not take in string input as argument. I could convert string to integer but how do I convert it to some class object like Pin/Cell

Comment: you need to return a variant

Comment: `auto` doesnt mean "arbitrary type" but it just means the compiler can figure it out by some means, but it is still one specific type.

Comment: @Richard Or `std::any`.

Comment: You can use `auto` when you call the function, and the compiler will deduce the value of the returned value from the function declaration.

Comment: @Actarus That's terribly misleading.

Comment: decltype(auto) can be used for this case

Comment: @HariomSingh, No it can't, as the function still needs exactly one static return type.

Comment: @HariomSingh auto doesnt mean you can start returning different types from the same function.

Comment: @user0042 I think the flexibility `std::any` offers isn't really needed in this case and the `std::variant` case has clearer access syntax IMO.

Comment: @user0042 Indeed, I might didn't answer to the question, but do you suggest that my comment is wrong ? Don't we (also) use the `auto` keyword when calling a function (I usually use it to avoid repeating the type as for `auto iter = myVectorOfWhatever.begin();` ?

Comment: @Actarus You can use `auto` as well as return type of the function. All the returned types need to evaluate to the same type though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return type of a function must be able to be determined at compile-time. C++ is a statically-typed language. `auto` does not mean "could be anything", it means "will be deduced at compile-time".

If you have a function which needs to potentially return multiple types, you'll want to use `std::variant` (in C++17) or `boost::variant` (pre-C++17, but requires use of the Boost Library).

In your case specifically, since some of your calls can return nothing (as demarcated by `void`), it might also be good to place this variant inside an `optional` (also C++17, or `boost::optional` if pre-C++17):

```
using return_t = std::optional<std::variant<unsigned int, Class>>;

return_t find_and_execute(std::vector<std::string> const& cmd) {
    if(cmd.at(0) == "square") {return square(stoi(cmd.at(1)));} // unsigned_int
    if(cmd.at(0) == "cube") {return cube(stoi(cmd.at(1)));}     // unsigned_int
    if(cmd.at(0) == "open_file") {open_file(cmd.at(1)); return {};}        //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "read_lib") {read_lib(cmd.at(1)); return {};}          //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "read_verilog") {read_verilog(cmd.at(1)); return {};}  //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "set_top") {set_top(cmd.at(1)); return {};}            //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "get_pin") {return get_pin(cmd.at(1));}     // Class object
}

return_t result = find_and_execute({std::string("square"), std::string("13")});
if(result) {//Should always be true
    try {
        unsigned int & value = std::get<unsigned int>(*result);
    } catch (std::bad_variant_access const&) {}
}

result = find_and_execute({std::string("open_file"), std::string("File.txt")});
if(!result) {//Should always be true
    /*...*/
}

result = find_and_execute({std::string("get_pin"), std::string("EAX")});
if(result) {//Should always be true
    try {
        Class & value = std::get<Class>(*result);
    } catch (std::bad_variant_access const&) {}
}
```

### EDIT:

An alternate version, as suggested by @chris, uses `std::monostate` to avoid the use of `std::optional`. This may be a better interface for you, depending on the circumstances.

```
using return_t = std::variant<std::monostate, unsigned int, Class>;

return_t find_and_execute(std::vector<std::string> const& cmd) {
    if(cmd.at(0) == "square") {return square(stoi(cmd.at(1)));} // unsigned_int
    if(cmd.at(0) == "cube") {return cube(stoi(cmd.at(1)));}     // unsigned_int
    if(cmd.at(0) == "open_file") {open_file(cmd.at(1)); return {};}        //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "read_lib") {read_lib(cmd.at(1)); return {};}          //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "read_verilog") {read_verilog(cmd.at(1)); return {};}  //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "set_top") {set_top(cmd.at(1)); return {};}            //void
    if(cmd.at(0) == "get_pin") {return get_pin(cmd.at(1));}     // Class object
}

return_t result = find_and_execute({std::string("square"), std::string("13")});
try {
    unsigned int & value = std::get<unsigned int>(result);
} catch (std::bad_variant_access const&) {}

result = find_and_execute({std::string("open_file"), std::string("File.txt")});
//Could query for it if you really needed to
//try {
    //std::monostate & value = std::get<std::monostate>(result);
//} catch (std::bad_variant_access const&) {}

result = find_and_execute({std::string("get_pin"), std::string("EAX")});
try {
    Class & value = std::get<Class>(*result);
} catch (std::bad_variant_access const&) {}
```

Comment: As an alternative to `std::optional<std::variant<...>>`, you could use `std::variant<std::monostate, ...>`.

Comment: `std::any` would be more flexible, since it doesn't require to specify the types aforehead. Though harder to deduce for the caller, what's really returned.

Comment: @chris Good tip.

Comment: @user0042 I don't really like the use of `std::any` as a de-facto solution to this kind of problem. It mandates heap-storage of objects, and I consider the requirement to specify the types beforehand to be a good thing, not a bad thing.

Comment: @user0042 std::any should be a last resort.

Comment: @Xirema. Thanks. I got that, is there any way to do this without C++17 or including boost. something in raw c++?

Comment: @user0042 You should only use `any` when you really need *any* type or the list is just to large.  For a few different types `variant` is a much more appropriate type and is light weight,

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni This is technically how `union` objects were originally used; `std::variant` is the type-safe version of vanilla `union`s. So there's nothing stopping you from defining a `union` and solving it that way. Personally, I'd look around online for an implementation of `variant`, since implementations have existed since the C++03 days, and it's extremely likely you'll find a valid implementation for a version of C++ before C++17, without needing to install boost (though, FYI, `<boost/variant>` should be header-only, and usable without having to pull in the rest of boost).

Comment: @Xirema. Just to clarify, if I use boost::variant instead of std::variant. Do I still use the std::monostate, or is there a similar bosst::monostate?

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni The boost equivalent to `std::monostate` is `boost::blank`.

Comment: Edit: I have another question. All my functions do not take in string input as argument. I could convert string to integer but how do I convert it to some class object like Pin/Cell?

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni Post a new question with your new issue, don't tack it onto this question. As for how you do it: `variant` plus the use of *Visitors* is how people usually solve that particular problem.